# Java Generics: compareTo and "capture#1-of ?"

Tags: java, generics, comparable

The following gives me an error message:

```
public static List<Comparable<?>> merge(Set<List<Comparable<?>>> lists) {
    List<Comparable<?>> result = new LinkedList<Comparable<?>>();
    HashBiMap<List<Comparable<?>>, Integer> location = HashBiMap.create();

    int totalSize;
    for (List<Comparable<?>> l : lists) {
        location.put(l, 0);
        totalSize += l.size();
    }

    boolean first;
    List<Comparable<?>> lowest; //the list with the lowest item to add
    int index;

    while (result.size() < totalSize) {
        first = true;

        for (List<Comparable<?>> l : lists) {
            if (! l.isEmpty()) {
                if (first) {
                    lowest = l;
                }
                else if (l.get(location.get(l)).compareTo(lowest.get(location.get(lowest))) <= 0) { //error here
                    lowest = l;
                }
            }
        }
        index = location.get(lowest);
        result.add(lowest.get(index));
        lowest.remove(index);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The error is:

```
The method compareTo(capture#1-of ?) in the type Comparable<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable<capture#2-of ?>)
```

What's going on here? I made the type of everything `Comparable` so I could call `.compareTo` and sort this list. Am I using generics incorrectly?

Comment: Some of those <?> needs to be <T>, but I don't have time this minute to sort this into an answer. If no one else does I'll come back later.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`List<?>` means "List of anything", so two objects with this type are not the same: One could be a list of `String`, the other a list of `BigDecimal`. Obviously, those are not the same.

`List<T>` means "List of anything but when you see `T` again, it's the same `T`".

You must tell the compiler when you mean the same type in different places. Try:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> merge(Set<List<T>> lists) {
    List<T> result = new LinkedList<T>();
    HashBiMap<List<T>, Integer> location = HashBiMap.create();
```

[EDIT] So what does `<T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T>` mean? The first part defines a type `T` with the following properties: It must implement the interface `Comparable<? super T>` (or `Comparable<X>` where `X` is also defined in terms of `T`).

`? super T` means that the type which the `Comparable` supports must `T` or one of its super types.

Imagine for a moment this inheritance: `Double extends Integer extends Number`. This is not correct in Java but imagine that `Double` is just an `Integer` plus a fraction part. In this scenario, a `Comparable` which works for `Number` also works for `Integer` and `Double` since both derive from `Number`. So `Comparable<Number>` would satisfy the `super` part for `T` being `Number`, `Integer` or `Double`.

As long as each of these types support the `Comparable` interface, they also satisfy the first part of the declaration. This means, you can pass in `Number` for `T` and the resulting code will also work when there are `Integer` and `Double` instances in the lists. If you `Integer` for `T`, you can still use `Double` but `Number` is not possible because it doesn't satisfy `T extends Comparable` anymore (the `super` part would still work, though).

The next step is to understand that the expression between `static` and `List` just declares the properties of the type `T` which is used later in the code. This way, you don't have to repeat this long declaration over and over again. It's part of the behavior of the method (like `public`) and not part of the actual code.

Comment: I've fixed my answer. This code compiles. It you get errors when you use it, remove the `<? super T>` but it should work. Oh, and replace `LinkedList` with `ArrayList`. It's much faster and uses much less memory.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` means?

Comment: You don't want to know ... ;) Okay, see my edits but don't try too hard to understand. This is why no one likes wildcards in generics.